# Trying to exec python in golang using exec.Command(

Tags: python, go

```
func execPython(fPath, colName, srv  string) (){
fmt.Println("Inside execPython")
cmd:= "python rfsvmchurn.py"
arg0 := "-fp " + fPath
arg1 := "-srv " + srv
arg2 := "-col " + colName
if err := exec.Command(cmd, arg0, arg1, arg2).Run(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Python Execution Error :",err)
}
```

}

getting error 
  Python Execution Error : exec: "python rfsvmchurn.py": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: Perhaps make `rfsvmchurn.py` an argument instead of including it as part of `cmd`.

Comment: Tried rfsvmchurn.py as argument, it also gives the same error

Comment: The *exact* same error?

Comment: Python Execution Error : exec: "python ": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: Try using the full absolute path to the python script. If that works then the python script is not in a place that your program can find it (either in the PATH as the error says or your program's working directory).

Comment: Also tried giving path like /usr/bin/python. But getting the same error

Comment: Is there really a space inside the quotes in the error message (`"python "`)?  If so, make sure `cmd` is just `"python"` (no spaces).

Comment: Yes removed spaces, but now getting this error Python Execution Error : exit status 1

Comment: Thanks, its working. the exit status 1 is due to issue in python file

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably that you're passing flags and their arguments as a single string. You should instead do:

```
func execPython(fPath, colName, srv  string) (){
    fmt.Println("Inside execPython")
    arg0 := "-fp " + fPath
    arg1 := "-srv " + srv
    arg2 := "-col " + colName
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "rfsvmchurn.py", "-fp", fPath, "-srv", srv, "-col", colName)
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Python Execution Error :",err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting same error   Python Execution Error : exec: "python rfsvmchurn.py": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: Try `./rfsvmchurn.py` instead?

Comment: Wait, actually, are you sure you passed "python" and "rfsvmchurn.py" as separate arguments? That error makes it sound like you had them as the same string.

Comment: Yes I tried like that, and now I am getting this error Python Execution Error : exit status 1

Comment: Thanks, its working. the exit status 1 is due to issue in python file